# Find a vector in a dot product such that an inequation is satisfied

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization

The problem I'm dealing with is as follows. Given the inequation:

$c_1 \langle \boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{x} \rangle - c_2 \ge 0$

where $\langle *, * \rangle$ is the dot product and $c_1, c_2, \boldsymbol{a}$ are known and $c_1, c_2 > 0$, find $\min \boldsymbol{x}$ such that the above inequation is satisfied.

I've tried to solve $c_1 \langle \boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{x} \rangle - c_2 = 0$ but it results in infinite solutions, which is hard to program (I'm writing Python code). So I think maybe an inequation will relax the problem. Is there any way to estimate $\boldsymbol{x}$? I wonder if we can have a minimization solution that produces an expression to compute $\boldsymbol{x}$.

As I'm not very strong in math (I have basic knowledge in linear algebra), a detailed explanation or pointers/references are very much appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by $\min x$? Is it $\min \Vert x \Vert$?

Comment: I mean the minimum vector $\boldsymbol{x}$, as if we're trying to find the lowest point in a plane (imagine gradient descent).

Comment: What is the minimum of a vector? I don't know what the lowest point in a plane is!?! Can you explain?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for the confusion, what I mean is something like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent, but of course I may have understood the problem completely wrong...I wonder if the analogy of gradient descent can be applied in this case or not.

Comment: And if I refer to the wikipedia article you linked to, **what is the function $F$ you're trying to minimize**? $F$ should be a real valued function. This is not clear to me in your question.

Comment: You're right. It seems I did not formulate the problem correctly. It was part of a reasoning I'm trying to prove but I think I made a mistake here, because there is indeed no function $F$ in this problem... Thanks for all your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the positivity of $c_1$, your inequality condition is equivalent to $$\langle \boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{x} \rangle \ge  \dfrac{c_2}{c_1} \ \iff \ a_1x_1+a_2x_2 \ge  \dfrac{c_2}{c_1}\tag{1}$$

which is one of the two closed half-planes with boundary the line having equation:

$$a_1x_1+a_2x_2 =  \dfrac{c_2}{c_1} \tag{2}$$

Which (affine) half-plane ? Answer: the one which doesn't contain the origin, because if you take $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$, condition (1) isn't fulfilled.

Remark: I have assumed we were dealing with a planar issue with coordinates $(x_1,x_2)$. If we are in an $n$-dimensional context, we will write (1) under the form:

$$\sum_k a_kx_k \ge  \dfrac{c_2}{c_1}$$

with "half-plane" replaced by "half-space" delimited by an affine hyperplane.

Edit: if you are looking for an $x=(x_1;x_2)$ satisfying (1), here is a deterministic way to obtain a solution.

Let $a=(a_1,a_2)$:

- if $a=0$: clearly, no $x$ can exist.
- if $a \ne 0$, either : $a_1 \ne 0$ ; in this case take $x=(x_1;x_2)=(\tfrac{c_2}{c_1a_1};0)$ ; otherwise $a_2 \ne 0$, in this case take $x=(x_1;x_2)=(0;\tfrac{c_2}{c_1a_2})$;

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So it means I'll need to generate random values for $\boldsymbol{x}$ (except one with all 0's values) until $\langle a, x \rangle = \frac{c_2}{c_1}$ is satisfied?

Comment: In this case, would $x_n$ be 0 as well?

Comment: I am going to include an answer to your question in my text.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for your help!